# Mongo Db nested grouping with applying start and end time filter

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

hi i want create nested group in aggregation, first group should be with category id and next group should be data between a day, starting from input start time from api, i need to group categories, within each category need to group day data(start time +24hrs) of a month with start and end time and my mongo db documents like

```
[
    {
        "category_id": "651e50405d2605dcb8d8e868",
        "value": 200,
        "created_at": {
            "$date": "2023-10-05T06:58:53.728Z"
        },
    },
    {
        "category_id": "651e50405d2605dcb8d8e86c",
        "value": 2000,
        "created_at": {
            "$date": "2023-10-25T09:17:56.723Z"
        },
    },
    {
        "category_id": "651e50405d2605dcb8d8e86b",
        "value": 1000,
        "created_at": {
            "$date": "2023-10-25T09:18:14.930Z"
        },
    },
    {
        "category_id": "651e50405d2605dcb8d8e872",
        "value": 2000,
        "created_at": {
            "$date": "2023-10-26T12:00:41.761Z"
        },
    },
    {
        "category_id": "651e50405d2605dcb8d8e86e",
        "value": 2000,
        "created_at": {
            "$date": "2023-10-26T12:00:59.349Z"
        },
    },
    {
        "category_id": "651e50405d2605dcb8d8e86c",
        "value": 1800,
        "created_at": {
            "$date": "2023-10-26T12:08:47.094Z"
        },
    },
    {
        "category_id": "651e50405d2605dcb8d8e86c",
        "value": 200,
        "created_at": {
            "$date": "2023-10-27T04:28:06.099Z"
        },
    },
    {
        "category_id": "651e50405d2605dcb8d8e86c",
        "value": 1000,
        "created_at": {
            "$date": "2023-10-27T04:28:18.356Z"
        },
    },
    {
        "category_id": "651e50405d2605dcb8d8e86e",
        "value": 2000,
        "created_at": {
            "$date": "2023-10-27T04:29:12.440Z"
        },
    }
]
```

and im grouping them with their category id

```
let data = await this.model.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            "created_at": { $gt: moment.utc(body.start_time).toDate(), $lte: moment.utc(body.end_time).toDate() }
        },
    },
    {
        $sort: { "created_at": 1 }
    },
    {
        $set: {
            total: 0
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$category_id",
            total_data: {
                $push: "$$ROOT"
            },
            total: { $sum: "$value" },
            max: { "$max": { value: "$value", category_id: "$category_id" } },
            min: { "$min": "$value" },
            avg: { "$avg": "$value" }
        }
    },
])
```

for the above query i got results like

```
[
    {
        "_id": "651e50405d2605dcb8d8e86f",
        "total_data": [
            {
                "_id": "651e50405d2605dcb8d8e868",
                "category_id": "651e50405d2605dcb8d8e86f",
                "value": 1500,
                "created_at": "2023-10-27T04:28:35.870Z",
                "total": 0
            }
        ],
        "total": 1500,
        "max": {
            "value": 1500,
            "category_id": "651e50405d2605dcb8d8e86f"
        },
        "min": 1500,
        "avg": 1500,
        "day": "2023-09-30T18:30:00.000Z"
    },
    {
        "_id": "651e50405d2605dcb8d8e86c",
        "total_data": [
            {
                "_id": "651e50405d2605dcb8d8e868",
                "category_id": "651e50405d2605dcb8d8e86f",
                "value": 1500,
                "created_at": "2023-10-27T04:28:35.870Z",
                "total": 0
            },
            {
                "category_id": "651e50405d2605dcb8d8e86c",
                "value": 1800,
                "created_at": {
                    "$date": "2023-10-26T12:08:47.094Z"
                }
            },
            {
                "category_id": "651e50405d2605dcb8d8e86c",
                "value": 200,
                "created_at": {
                    "$date": "2023-10-27T04:28:06.099Z"
                }
            },
            {
                "category_id": "651e50405d2605dcb8d8e86c",
                "value": 1000,
                "created_at": {
                    "$date": "2023-10-27T04:28:18.356Z"
                }
            }
        ],
        "total": 1500,
        "max": {
            "value": 1500,
            "category_id": "651e50405d2605dcb8d8e86f"
        },
        "min": 1500,
        "avg": 1500,
        "day": "2023-09-30T18:30:00.000Z"
    },
    .........
]
```

what i need is

```
[
    {
        "_id": "651e50405d2605dcb8d8e86f",
        "day_wise": [
            {
                "day": "2023-09-30T18:30:00.000Z",
                "data": [
                    {
                        "_id": "651e50405d2605dcb8d8e868",
                        "category_id": "651e50405d2605dcb8d8e86f",
                        "value": 1500,
                        "created_at": "2023-10-27T04:28:35.870Z",
                        "total": 0
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],....other keys
    },
    {
        "_id": "651e50405d2605dcb8d8e86c",
        "day_wise": [
            {
                "day": "2023-09-26T18:30:00.000Z",
                "data": [
                    {
                        "category_id": "651e50405d2605dcb8d8e86c",
                        "value": 1800,
                        "created_at": {
                            "$date": "2023-10-26T12:08:47.094Z"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "day": "2023-09-27T18:30:00.000Z",
                "data": [
                    {
                        "_id": "651e50405d2605dcb8d8e868",
                        "category_id": "651e50405d2605dcb8d8e86f",
                        "value": 1500,
                        "created_at": "2023-10-27T04:28:35.870Z",
                        "total": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "category_id": "651e50405d2605dcb8d8e86c",
                        "value": 200,
                        "created_at": {
                            "$date": "2023-10-27T04:28:06.099Z"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "category_id": "651e50405d2605dcb8d8e86c",
                        "value": 1000,
                        "created_at": {
                            "$date": "2023-10-27T04:28:18.356Z"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        ...other keys
    }
]
```

here in api im sending start time and end time of a month and in response i need each category data of each day(start time + 24 hrs)

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this, I made two changes to the aggregation pipeline:

1. I added a new field `day` to each document using the `$addFields` stage. This is the day the document was created and after converting the `created_at` field to a string like "YYYY-MM-DD".
2. Next, I've added two `$group` stages.

2.1. First one groups by both `category_id` and `day`.
This creates a group for each day within each category.

It will produce output like this:

```json
{
  "_id": {
    "category_id": "651e50405d2605dcb8d8e86e",
    "day": "2023-10-26"
  },
  "avg": 2000,
  "data": [
    {
      "_id": "5a934e000102030405000004",
      "category_id": "651e50405d2605dcb8d8e86e",
      "created_at": "2023-10-26T12:00:59.349Z",
      "day": "2023-10-26",
      "value": 2000
    }
  ],
  "max": {
    "category_id": "651e50405d2605dcb8d8e86e",
    "value": 2000
  },
  "min": 2000,
  "total": 2000
}
```

2.2. Second `$group` groups these groups by `category_id` only, resulting in a single group for each category.
Each group contains a `day_wise` array, where each element represents a day and contains docs created on that day, along with the total, maximum, minimum, and average for that day.

Here is the full code:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  // your "$match": for created_at goes here
  {
    $sort: {
      "created_at": 1
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      "day": {
        $dateToString: {
          format: "%Y-%m-%d",
          date: "$created_at"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        category_id: "$category_id",
        day: "$day"
      },
      data: {
        $push: "$$ROOT"
      },
      total: {
        $sum: "$value"
      },
      max: {
        "$max": {
          value: "$value",
          category_id: "$category_id"
        }
      },
      min: {
        "$min": "$value"
      },
      avg: {
        "$avg": "$value"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id.category_id",
      day_wise: {
        $push: {
          day: "$_id.day",
          data: "$data",
          total: "$total",
          max: "$max",
          min: "$min",
          avg: "$avg"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

Also, you can see this query work in the [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/V8JM8w1t74R).

Comment: hi thanks for replay, and with date its working perfectly but my blocker was i need to filter one day data from starting time because from client side i will send his start time, for eg im in IST time zone and my db is in UTC now im sending start time as 2023-10-02 00:00:00 but my query start time will be 2023-10-01 18:30:00(in UTC) now i have to group each day data for each day like (day1 : 2023-10-01 18:30:00 to 2023-10-02 18:30:00, day2 : 2023-10-02 18:30:00 to 2023-10-03 18:30:00 .....) for that ive done before only for that, but now i have to group another id.

Comment: you can check that query [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/MQYrw-RGtD7)

Comment: I recommend you opening a new question for the new question you have